# Android Studio an array in onStop()

Tags: android, android-activity

why does the program crash at "String temp_str = string_array[1]" ?
Logcat: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public String string_array[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String string_array[]=new String[10];

    string_array[1]="word1";
    string_array[2]="word2";
    string_array[3]="word3";


}


@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    String temp_str = string_array[1];

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete this line in onCreate():

```
String string_array[]=new String[10];
```

In class scope use this declaration:

```
public String[] string_array = new String[10];
```

And delete this one:

```
public String string_array[];
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `String string_array[]` twice. Once in class scope and once in `onCreate()` method.

For intended behavior, delete the declaration inside `onCreate()`

For example, delete this line inside `onCreate()`

`String string_array[]=new String[10];`

Answer (score 2):

Program crash because you are declaring localy (in `onCreate()`) second variable with name `string_array[]` and you initialize only this one variable. Your global variable `public String string_array[]` isn't initialized anywhere so is null. 
To make this code working you should delete declaration in onCreate() and move initialization to global variable declaration:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public String string_array[] = new String[10];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    string_array[1]="word1";
    string_array[2]="word2";
    string_array[3]="word3";


}


@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    String temp_str = string_array[1];

   }
}
```